# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data, thymeleaf

### Return List of objects

```
   @RequestMapping("/mvt")
            public String showMvt(Model model){
          
                    model.addAttribute("counts", mouvementRepository.findAll());
        
                return"mvt_";
            }
```

### Update one line controller

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/updateMvt/{idmvt}",method = {RequestMethod.GET})
            public String updateMvt(@PathVariable(value = "idmvt") int idcpn, @Valid @ModelAttribute("mvt") Mouvement mvt,BindingResult result) {
             mouvementRepository.save(mvt);
            return "redirect:/mvt";
        }
```

### I tried To edit lanes inside tr th:each like this

```
    <tr th:each="count:${counts}">
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/updateMvt/{idmvt}(idmvt=${count.idmvt})}" th:object="${count}" method="put">

                            <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>etat</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select class="select-css" th:field="*{count.etat}">
                                            <option th:value="Enregistrement">Enregistrement</option>
                                            <option th:value="Embarquement">Embarquement</option>
                                            <option th:value="Decollé">Decollé</option>
                                            <option th:value="Annulé" selected>Annulé</option>
                                            <option th:value="null" selected>Aucun</option>
                                            </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
```

I'm new to spring,i know this solution looks bad,but i'm trying to do my best.
so I tried to do it this way, but I get the error :

> Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'count'
> available as request attribute

### Update --------------------------------------------------------------------

so far I managed to create a wrapper class Like this

```
public class mvtForm {

        private int version;
        private List<Mouvement> mouvements;//Getters and setters are included
```

And in my controller I set the movements attribute like this :

```
@ModelAttribute("wrapper")
@RequestMapping(value = "/mvtall")
public String processQuery(@ModelAttribute mvtForm wrapper, Model model) {
    wrapper.setMouvements(mouvementRepository.findAll());
 
    model.addAttribute("wrapper",wrapper);

   return "mvt_all";
}
```

Now I got the view that I needed,
[image: View from Controller]

but Is there a way to submit PUT to each lane using JpaRepository ?

Answer (score 2):

th:object must reference an object from Model, not from iteration. So you need to pass count object to model in controller before loading the page, like for example by defining this method in your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("updateCount")
public Count count() {
    return new Count(); 
}
```

class Count should have a field int version that will be unique for each Count object, this is important for updating. Don't forget getters, setters and default constructor - this is important for Thymeleaf.

```
@ModelAttribute("listOfCounts")
public List<Count> listOfCounts() {
    return listOfCounts; //has to be predefined somewhere in class 
                         //as it will be reused throughout application. 
}
```

When you iterate you will be iterating over a listOfCounts. However when updating and pressing update button you will be binding the updateCount object. Make sure to have a hidden field with version in thymeleaf. With this when receiving the update request in your controller, you will receive the updateCount object with the correct version, you can find the correct Count object from the listOfCounts via version and update it.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: Hello again, but i want to assign object from th:each to th:object, because the goal after all this is to update fields in the same table and time as printing them.Any idea please ?

Comment: Thank you, i will try this solution